# Gumdrop shader is appearing as grey

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

I have followed Blender Guru's process of shading the Gum drop but I don't know why it is coming out as grey. I have pasted images of the final render and the shading nodes for the gumdrop.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What render engine? And what are the material settings (ie Alpha Blend)

Comment: hi. When I opened the file I saw that half of the nodes in the shader editor were gone. I re-did the nodes and this time it worked. I guess it was some kind of bug :P

Comment: Well, you already solved your problem, but I'm just curious: why the "geometry-nodes" tag? Your question gives no hint on what this has to do with geometry nodes. And if you suspected the problem to be related to _Geometry Nodes_ (like a missing _Set Material_ node for example), you probably should have added a screenshot of that nodetree, too. Since the material setup doesn't really explain what was missing a more elaborate answer might be helpful, this way other users could benefit from the solution as well.